# Como incrustar un ReportViewer en modo diseño en un formulario con VS 2017?

Tags: c#, reportviewer

No encuentro la manera de que me muestre el reporViewer en modo diseño en mi formulario con VS 2017. Alguien ha encontrado alguna solución para esto?. Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Cuando dices modo diseño te refieres cuando estas mirando el diseño del form con visual studio?

Comment: Por favor lee el artículo [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/)

Comment: Lo siento Ruslan, es mi primera consulta en este foro. No obstante, es una pregunta muy concreta acerca de la forma en la que se ve la herramienta reportviewer. Por supuesto que he mirado en muchísimas páginas y he visto una infinidad de videos, y en todos usan este reportviewer en forma diseño (se abre al arrastrarlo desde la caja de herramientas al formulario). Ya he conseguido abrirlo mediante código, pero simplemente quería saber si alguien me podía decir si VS 2017 no admitía usar esta herramienta en modo diseño.

Comment: Hola Denifer; sí me refiero a cuando arrastras el reportviewer sobre tu formulario, y este se abre con el formato del reporte para que en modo diseño puedas trabajar con el y asociarle los DataTable correspondientes y darle formato al reporte. Gracias.